# Dynamic inline importing raw SVG in Vue.js & Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

So I am trying to import SVG as string into my Vue component using inline import on Vite as follows

```
<script>
const getSvgIcon = async (name) => {
  const module = await import(`../icons/${name}.svg?raw`)
  return module.default
}

export default {
  props: {
    name: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      svg: null,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name: {
      async handler(name) {
        this.svg = await getSvgIcon(name)
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-html="svg"></div>
</template>
```

This works just fine when running on `npm run dev` mode.

However, the issue happens when running `npm run build`, I end up getting `Error: Unknown variable dynamic import` apparently because I'm using `?raw` suffix.

Is there a solution or is this a handicap by Vite as of now?

Comment: I think this is a Vite bug. I recommend reporting a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 20):

*As @tony19 commented, this is probably a bug. I opened an issue which you can follow [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6992).*

As a workaround to make your code working though, follow below:

#### Step 1:

Turn all your SVGs into Vue components. In that way, you can have better management. In order to do that, you simply edit the file name replacing from `.svg` to `.vue` and wrapping the content inside `template` tag.

If you want to keep `svg` files though, you can use [vite-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader) plugin and with this, you will be able to do:

`import IconComponent from './my-icon.svg?component'`

#### Step 2:

Create an SVG icon component:

```html
<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    dynamicComponent() {
      const name = this.name;

      return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./icons/${name}.vue`));
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
</template>
```

#### Step 3

Now you can import `SvgIcon.vue` and use the name of the SVG icon like this:

```html
<script>
import SvgIcon from './components/SvgIcon.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    SvgIcon
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <SvgIcon name="user" />
</template>
```

[See it live on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ip1an5?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/components/SvgIcon.vue)

---

If you like the above approach, I recently wrote an article about it:

[Unified SVG icons with Vite, Vue 3, Quasar and Pinia](https://dev.to/the_one/unified-svg-icons-with-vite-vue-3-quasar-and-pinia-2c01)

Comment: This is interesting, it is a much more elegant approach to this matter, however using `vite-svg-loader` causes the same dynamic import error because of that `?component` suffix again. I don't want to convert the icons to vue templates because they are not one or two.. but if this bug takes long to fix I guess I will have to go with this...

Comment: Hey your blog post doesn't seem to work anymore, and there's no archive version of it. Do you still have this blog post laying around somewhere?

Comment: @Alice can you check again now please?

Answer (score 9):

Look at this example created by myself.

```
<template>
    <i v-html="svg" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps({
        icon: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        src: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
    });
    const path = props.src ? props.src : '';
    const file = `${path}icon-${props.icon}`;
    const modules = import.meta.glob('../../assets/icons/**/*.svg', {
        as: 'raw',
        eager: true,
    });
    const svg = computed(() => {
        return modules['../../assets/icons/' + file + '.svg'] ?? modules['../../assets/icons/icon-logo-cone.svg'];
    });
</script>
```

This is all you need to dynamically load your SVG in a nice and minimalistic component.

Ah don't forget you can also change the colors of your svg, by using plain css.

Usage:

```
<UiIcon
    class="w-4 text-gray-600"
    icon="search"
/>
```

Comment: Finally an in-house solution that doesn't require a plugin, thank you ! It could probably be optimised somewhat though, atm every time the component is called the we glob the entire folder. It maybe worth doing this only once and storing the list of icons

Comment: Even if this looks more straightforward, I would not recommend it. You expose your application to XSS attacks. Not only because you use the v-html attribute but also in combination with the v-html and SVG is a big no, regarding security-wise.

Comment: Regards calling every time, I think you can just create another script tag and add the glob declaration in there, of you could put that file as the index of the svg folder and just import.

Comment: only a risk if the data is from an untrusted source

Answer (score 2):

Here is another wrapper around the [vite-svg-loader](https://github.com/jpkleemans/vite-svg-loader)

Create an SVG icon component `InlineSvg.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
  import { shallowRef } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({
    src: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  })

  let svgComponent = shallowRef(null)

  props.src
    .then((module) => {
      svgComponent.value = module.default
    })
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="svgComponent"/>
</template>
```

Then use:

```js
<script setup>
  import InlineSvg from '@/components/InlineSvg.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <InlineSvg
    class="w-32 h-32"
    :src="import('@/assets/svg/logo.svg')"/>
</template>
```

The pitfall of this approach is that it creates many chunks in production build for each usage of InlineSvg component.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best beautiful solution :)
Vite docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

```
<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      icons: import.meta.glob(`./**/*.svg`)
    }
  },

  computed: {
    icon() {
      return defineAsyncComponent(() => this.icons[`./${this.name}.svg`]())
    },
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="icon" :class="className" />
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I use this, I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid async component load result: https://domain.test/resources/js/Icons/linkbackward.svg