# How to transform an external svg to a Vue3 component?

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 project with Vite, Typescript and script setup for my components.

My goal is to get an svg image from an S3 bucket (so an external url) and use it as an inline svg in my component. I need to be able to set props, like viewBox and fill on the svg itself. I have found an example of what I want using svg's inside the project (so not with external url) via [this Stack Overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176408/dynamic-inline-importing-raw-svg-in-vue-js-vite).

Currently I use fetch to get the svg and then transform it to an svg element with DomParser. After that, I want to pass it to `<component>`, but I get stuck.

This is my code:

```js
<template>
  <div
    class="svg-box"
    :style="{ height: props.height + 'px', width: props.width + 'px' }">
    <component
      :is="dynamicSvg"
      v-if="dynamicSvg"
      ref="icon"
      :fill="props.fill"
      :viewBox="viewBox"
      :class="name" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  ref,
  onBeforeMount,
} from 'vue'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

interface dynamicSvgProps {
  name?: string
  fill?: string
  width?: number
  height?: number
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<dynamicSvgProps>(), {
  name: 'placeholder',
})

const dynamicSvg: Ref<string | undefined | null> = ref(null)

const icon: Ref<SVGSVGElement | null> = ref(null)
const svgBox: Ref<SVGSVGElement | null> = ref(null)

const viewBox = '0 0 24 24' //  hardcoded for this example 

const fetchSvg = async (svgName: string) => {
  let url = `https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/${svgName}.svg`

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((svgText) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser()
      const svgElement = parser
        .parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml')
        .querySelector('svg')

      // svgBox.value.append(svgElement)  if I use this, the svg is appended but not editable with props

     //  here I am trying to transform the svg element to a component so I can pass it to <component>, but this doesn't work
      const svgComponent = defineComponent(() => {
        return { render: () => h('svg', svgElement ) }
      })

      return svgComponent
    })
}


onBeforeMount(async () => {
  dynamicSvg.value = await fetchSvg('check') //  for this example I don't use props for the name
})

//  if I would use an internal svg file, the following code would work in stead of using fetchSvg
const importSvg = async (svgName: string): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  if (svgName) return await import(`../../assets/icons/${svgName}.svg`)
}
</script>
```

Does anyone have experience with using external SVG's like this? Or can help point me in the right direction? Also, is using a DOM Parser a good idea here or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, turning it into a real component means that you have to turn the svg string into a template by adding bind statements to it, and then run the template compiler (which you specifically need to add to your build). A lot of work for a moderate result...

I think an easier way to do this is to remove the `<svg>` tag and extract attributes and content from it. Then you can put those into your own svg tag, to which you set the content with `v-html` and bind and possibly replace the old attributes:

```html
<svg 
  v-bind="attributes"
  v-html="content"
  :fill="fill"
/>
```

You can extract content and attributes from the SVG document:

```
const parseSvg = (svgString) => {
  const svgDom = new DOMParser()
   .parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml')
   .querySelector('svg')
  
  const attributeEntries = [...svgDom.attributes].map(a => [a.name, a.value])
  return {
    content: svgDom.innerHTML,
    attributes: Object.fromEntries(attributeEntries)
  }
}
```

Here is a [playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)