# Vue 3 - Svgator player is always undefined

Tags: vue.js, svgator

Currently I've made an svg animation using SVGator.

I've imported it as an asset to my application and I was trying to make it run.

I've made it work following this [Docs](https://www.svgator.com/help/getting-started/add-animated-svg-to-vue-js)

But, as I may need to create a bunch of animations, I've tried to make this more generic.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent, h, component, watch } from 'vue';
import exampleSvg from '@assets/example.svg?raw';
interface IComponentProperties {
  svg: string;
}
const componentProperties = withDefaults(defineProps<IComponentProperties>(), {
  svg: () => exampleSvg,
});
const element = ref<HTMLElement>();

const animatedSvg = defineComponent({
  render() {
    return h('svg', { innerHTML: componentProperties.svg, ref: element });
  },
});
function runAnimation() {
  if (!element.value) return;
  const { firstChild } = element.value;
  const svg = firstChild as any;
  svg?.svgatorPlayer?.play();
}
watch(
  () => element.value,
  () => {
    runAnimation();
  },
  {
    immediate: true,
  }
);
</script>
<template>
  <Component :is="animatedSvg" />
</template>
```

Here is a full vue app with the same [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yrdbcq?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Why **svg?.svgatorPlayer** is always null?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question, it seems your `firstChild` is an HTMLElement with inside any `svgatorPlayer` provided.

You are treating the svg as a string using the `?raw`.

For fixing this you must follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176408/dynamic-inline-importing-raw-svg-in-vue-js-vite).

Second of all after reading the documentation provided, you are not using the `Javascript` with the `svg` you are putting it as a string this is why your `svgatorPlayer` equals to null because it doesn't exist while the js is not executed a solution will be to put the `svg` in a `v-html` to execute it but be carefull with the XSS injections.

```html
<template>
  <div v-html="exampleSvg"></div>
  <Component :is="animatedSvg" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work.

For anyone else that is struggling with it, here is my Vue3 Component that handles it.

> **Important**: This component was designed to work with the SvgGator animated svg, using javascript and it was tested only using animations exported with **Animation Start** "Programmatic" option

```js
<script setup lang="tsx">
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { ref, defineComponent, h, component, watch,computed } from 'vue';
declare type ComponentSize =
    | number
    | string
    | { width: number; height: number; minHeight?: number; minWidth?: number; maxHeight?: number; maxWidth?: number };
export interface ILoadingLogoComponentProperties {
    base64RawSvg?: string;
    speed?: number;
    indeterminate?: boolean;
    iterations?: number;
    fps?: number;
    direction?: number;
    size?: ComponentSize;
}
export interface IAnimatedPlayer {
    play: () => void;
    pause: () => void;
    stop: () => void;
    toggle: () => void;
    restart: () => void;
    setSpeed: (speed: number) => void;
    indeterminate: () => void;
    setIterations: (iterations: number) => void;
    setFps: (fps: number) => void;
    setDirection: (direction: number) => void;
    isPlaying: () => boolean;
    setOptions: (options?: IAnimatedPlayerOptions) => void;
    state: () => string;
}
export interface IAnimatedPlayerOptions {
    speed?: number;
    iterations?: number;
    fps?: number;
    direction?: number;
    indeterminate: boolean;
}
export interface ISvgElementAndScript {
    svgElement: any;
    script: string;
}
const componentProperties = withDefaults(defineProps<ILoadingLogoComponentProperties>(), {
    direction: 1,
    fps: 60,
    indeterminate: false,
    iterations: 1,
    speed: 1,
});
const animatedSvgElement = ref<HTMLElement>();
const animatedSvg = ref<any>(createComponent());
const componentKey = ref<number>(0);
const animatedPlayer = ref<IAnimatedPlayer>();
function createComponent(): any {
    return defineComponent({
        render() {
            if (isBase64(componentProperties.base64RawSvg)) {
                return h('svg', {
                    ref: animatedSvgElement,
                    innerHTML: decodeBase64(componentProperties.base64RawSvg),
                    style: {
                        ...size.value,
                    },
                });
            }
            return returnInvalidSvg();
        },
    });
}
const size = computed(() => {
    if (typeof componentProperties.size === 'number')
        return { width: componentProperties.size, height: componentProperties.size };
    if (typeof componentProperties.size === 'string')
        return { width: componentProperties.size, height: componentProperties.size };
    return componentProperties.size;
});
function isBase64(text?: string) {
    if (!text) return false;
    const base64Regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+$/;
    return base64Regex.test(text);
}
function decodeBase64(text?: string) {
    if (!text) return '';
    return Buffer.from(text, 'base64');
}
function returnInvalidSvg() {
    return (
        <div>
            Invalid SVG. <b>base64RawSvg</b> Must be a valid base64 svg{' '}
        </div>
    );
}
function getSvgElementAndScript(): ISvgElementAndScript | undefined | null {
    if (!animatedSvgElement.value) return null;
    const { firstChild } = animatedSvgElement.value;
    if (!firstChild) return null;
    for (const child of firstChild?.childNodes ?? []) {
        if (child.nodeName !== 'script') continue;
        if (!child.textContent) continue;
        return { svgElement: firstChild, script: child.textContent };
    }
    return null;
}
function canRunAnimation(svgElementAndScript?: ISvgElementAndScript | null) {
    if (!svgElementAndScript) return false;
    if (!svgElementAndScript.svgElement) return false;
    return !!svgElementAndScript.script;
}
function createOptionsBasedOnComponentProperties(): IAnimatedPlayerOptions {
    return {
        speed: componentProperties.speed,
        direction: componentProperties.direction,
        fps: componentProperties.fps,
        indeterminate: componentProperties.indeterminate,
        iterations: componentProperties.iterations,
    };
}
function startEmbededScript(script: string): void {
    try {
        eval(script);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Failed to run embeded script');
    }
}
function runAnimation() {
    const svgElementAndScript = getSvgElementAndScript();
    if (!canRunAnimation(svgElementAndScript)) return;
    const { svgElement, script } = svgElementAndScript!;
    try {
        startEmbededScript(script);
        if (!svgElement.svgatorPlayer) return;
        const svgatorPlayer = svgElement.svgatorPlayer;
        const options = createOptionsBasedOnComponentProperties();
        animatedPlayer.value = createAnimatedPlayer(svgatorPlayer, options);
        animatedPlayer.value.play();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
function incrementComponentKey() {
    componentKey.value += 1;
}
function createAnimatedPlayer(player?: any, options?: IAnimatedPlayerOptions): IAnimatedPlayer {
    let _isPlaying = true;
    function play() {
        if (!player) return;
        player.play();
        _isPlaying = true;
    }
    function pause() {
        if (!player) return;
        player.pause();
        _isPlaying = false;
    }
    function stop() {
        if (!player) return;
        player.stop();
        _isPlaying = false;
    }
    function toggle() {
        if (!player) return;
        _isPlaying ? pause() : play();
    }
    function isPlaying(): boolean {
        return _isPlaying;
    }
    function restart() {
        if (!player) return;
        _isPlaying = false;
        player.restart();
        _isPlaying = true;
        console.log('restarted');
    }
    function state() {
        if (!player) return 'not_inialized';
        return player.state;
    }
    function setSpeed(speed: number) {
        if (!player) return;
        if (speed >= 100) {
            player.set('speed', 100);
            return;
        }
        if (speed <= 0) {
            player.set('speed', 0);
            return;
        }
        player.set('speed', speed);
    }
    function setDirection(direction: number) {
        if (!player) return;
        player.set('direction', direction);
    }
    function setFps(fps: number) {
        if (!player) return;
        if (fps >= 100) {
            player.set('fps', 100);
            return;
        }
        if (fps <= 0) {
            player.set('fps', 0);
            return;
        }
        player.set('fps', fps);
    }

    function indeterminate() {
        setIterations(0);
    }
    function setIterations(interactions: number) {
        if (!player) return;
        player.set('iterations', interactions);
    }
    function setOptions(options?: IAnimatedPlayerOptions) {
        const persistedOptions: IAnimatedPlayerOptions = {
            speed: 1,
            direction: 1,
            fps: 60,
            iterations: 0,
            indeterminate: true,
            ...options,
        };
        setSpeed(persistedOptions.speed!);
        setDirection(persistedOptions.direction!);
        setFps(persistedOptions.fps!);
        if (persistedOptions.indeterminate) indeterminate();
        else setIterations(persistedOptions.iterations ?? 0);
    }
    setOptions(options);
    return {
        play,
        pause,
        toggle,
        stop,
        isPlaying,
        restart,
        setSpeed,
        setDirection,
        setFps,
        setOptions,
        indeterminate,
        setIterations,
        state,
    };
}

watch(
    () => componentProperties.size,
    () => {
        animatedSvg.value = createComponent();
        incrementComponentKey();
    },
    { immediate: true },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.base64RawSvg,
    () => {
        animatedSvg.value = createComponent();
        incrementComponentKey();
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);

watch(
    () => animatedSvgElement.value,
    () => {
        runAnimation();
        console.log(animatedPlayer.value?.state());
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.speed,
    () => {
        animatedPlayer.value?.setSpeed(componentProperties.speed);
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.direction,
    () => {
        animatedPlayer.value?.setDirection(componentProperties.direction);
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.fps,
    () => {
        animatedPlayer.value?.setFps(componentProperties.fps);
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.indeterminate,
    () => {
        animatedPlayer.value?.indeterminate();
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.iterations,
    () => {
        animatedPlayer.value?.setIterations(componentProperties.iterations ?? 0);
    },
    {
        immediate: true,
    },
);
</script>
<template>
  <Component :is="animatedSvg" :key="componentKey" />
</template>
```

## Pre requisites

You may need to install the following packages in order to work:

#### DEPENDENCIES

- "buffer": "^6.0.3"

#### DEV_DEPENDENCIES

- "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.1"
- "vite-svg-loader": "^4.0.0"

And modify your **vite.config.ts** to implemente those plugins

##### Imports

```
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader';
```

##### Plugins

```
 plugins: [
    svgLoader(),
    vueJsx(),
   //...rest of plugins
]
```

You can checkout a fully working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cpdw6q?file=src%2FApp.vue)